# "Missing" Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Runtime.win-arm & Microsoft.NetCore.App.Runtime.win-arm: Can't Build

Tags: .net, nuget-package, .net-8.0, windows-arm64, net-maui

In the process of upgrading a solution to .net 8 I've run into a build error I can't get around.

In short, I get two errors about missing Microsoft.*..win-arm Nuget Packages being unavailable to restore or install/find.

- error NU1102: Unable to find package **Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Runtime.win-arm** with version (= 8.0.0-preview.6.23329.11)
- error NU1102: - Found 125 version(s) in nuget.org [ Nearest version: 8.0.0-preview.4.23260.4 ]
- error NU1102: - Found 0 version(s) in Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages
- error NU1102: - Found 0 version(s) in C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs
- error NU1101: Unable to find package **Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.win-arm64**. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages, nuget.org

I've tried all of the following different ways so far:

- removed all VS versions and .net SDKs from system
- rebooting
- (re)installing only latest VS22 Preview (6) with .Net Preview component -installed.
- Installing latest .net 8 sdk preview manually
- (trying) to install ARM SDK and and ARM packages (wouldn't install x64 system)

Note that it seems both the required runtimes are installed (see bold below). But the error is about finding ARM variants in these, I believe.

Any help appreciated.

Dave G

Preview Tooling:
VS Studio Enterprise 17.7 Preview 6
dotnet --list-sdks

- 7.0.400-preview.23330.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
- 8.0.100-preview.6.23330.14 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

PM> dotnet --list-runtimes
'''
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.19 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
**Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 8.0.0-preview.6.23329.11** [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.19 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
**Microsoft.NETCore.App 8.0.0-preview.6.23329.7** [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.19 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 7.0.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 8.0.0-preview.6.23329.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
'''
Dave G

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem was an old explicit package include in the csproj file for

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK" Version="1.4.230628000-preview1" />
```

Removing the explicit package reference for Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK in csproj fixes the problem, presumably by permitting upstream dependencies to now "auto include" this reference as needed.

Hope hit helps someone else.